# Restricting field options in a profile on a contribution page

Tags: profile, contribution-page

I have a Contribution page for Membership Registration. In this form users create their Drupal account and made payment off-site, so using the Contribution page is the best option for me - webforms doesn't have everything I need :)

Membership is only open to UK residents and we don't want them to be able to choose another country.

However, database contact are from other countries. So we do need to have additional countries enabled.

Is there a way we can restrict the available option on this profile / contribution without disabling all on the site?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a field in a profile to be "View-only". So:

1. (If you haven't done it already) Set your **Default Country** to United Kingdom on **Administer > Localization > Languages, Currency, Location**.
2. In the profile on your membership page set the "Country" field to be "View-only".

Answer (score 0):

Not without some coding I think....The only thing I would try is create a Smart Group of everyone in the UK, perhaps you can limit the page for a group?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the public members registration page so we need to have it openly available. Was hoping someone out there may have built a hook for this purpose :)